# Issues on hosting a website in 000webhost.com

Tags: php, laravel, hosting

[this is the db properties in the hosting server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpxYF.png)So i am hosting my website that uses laravel, and i'll be honest i've done this before and it turn out without problem, but this time it's so frustrating, so after i uploaded my files, and my database to 000webhost.com i copy the app key from .env to /config/app.php and after that i added the new host and db name from 000webhost.com and that's it right ? it's supposed to work , but it showed this error

```
QueryException

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] ProxySQL Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'2a02:4780:bad:f00d::a' (using password: NO) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `blogs`)
```

i don't know if the database is already connected or not, and i don't even have a user named root, i've already changed it to what the 000webhost.com give me

so this is my .env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:WlIDPJllsrTTV6XCtZgprK+0iy9SjyhiyGQXsKa3VzI=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=id10203308_laravel1
DB_USERNAME=id10203308_laravel1
DB_PASSWORD=laravel1

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

and this is my app.php

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', base64_decode('WlIDPJllsrTTV6XCtZgprK+0iy9SjyhiyGQXsKa3VzI=')),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

and this is the controller that shows the welcome page

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Blog;

class Blog1Controller extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $blogs = DB::table('blogs')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(3);
        return view('welcome',[
            'blogs' => $blogs
        ]);
    }

}
```

and this is the routes

```
Auth::routes();Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')    
    ->name('home');Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@admin')    
    ->middleware('is_admin')    
    ->name('admin');
    Route::get('/posting','BlogController@index')->name('blog');
    Route::post('/posting','BlogController@store')->name('blog.store');
    Route::post('/profile','BlogController@thumbnail')->name('blog.thumb');
    Route::get('/','Blog1Controller@index')->name('blog');
    Route::get('/review','ReviewController@index');
```

Comment: Do you have fixed database credentials in `config/database.php`?

Comment: why it's called `ProxySQL`  it should be `mysql` not?

Comment: And check the database credentials at config/database.php as suggested it should be identicle to .env

Comment: ``` 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''), ``` you mean this ? @Jerodev

Comment: should i change that too ? @Jerodev

Answer (score 0):

000webhost is having issue in their end. You can check in the link: https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/sqlstate-hy000-1045-proxysql-error-access-denied-for-user/48044.

They told you to keep trying. And my suggestion is before you try again, clear your config cache from laravel app.

Comment: i'll try it again tomorrow then

Comment: sure. you should.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear cache files from storage because it cache .env variables.
If you can access your website files from ssh you need to run `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear` instead of deleting files

Comment: i tried, since i can't use cmd, i use route like this ``` Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
    return 'DONE'; //Return anything
}); ```

Comment: but it showed me this error ``` ErrorException

putenv() has been disabled for security reasons ```